# il2cpp decompiling unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui, декомпиляция

Мне нужно вытащить из игры весь UI (Цвета, иконки, координаты, материалы и.т.д.)
Игра на IL2CPP, Unity 2019.4.22, C#

Пробовал через il2cppDumper, и получил это.

```
    [Token(Token = "0x6002B5A")]
    [Address(RVA = "0x4F2E00", Offset = "0x4F1600", VA = "0x1804F2E00")]
    get
    {
        return null;
    }

// Token: 0x060033B8 RID: 13240 RVA: 0x00002053 File Offset: 0x00000253
[Token(Token = "0x6002B5B")]
[Address(RVA = "0x4F2980", Offset = "0x4F1180", VA = "0x1804F2980")]
private void OnEnable()
{
}

// Token: 0x060033B9 RID: 13241 RVA: 0x00002053 File Offset: 0x00000253
[Token(Token = "0x6002B5C")]
[Address(RVA = "0x4F2400", Offset = "0x4F0C00", VA = "0x1804F2400")]
public void CompassUpdate()
{
}

// Token: 0x060033BA RID: 13242 RVA: 0x00002053 File Offset: 0x00000253
[Token(Token = "0x6002B5D")]
[Address(RVA = "0x4F2A70", Offset = "0x4F1270", VA = "0x1804F2A70")]
private void UpdateCompassMarker(Vector3 rot, CompassMapMarker marker, MapNote forNote)
{
}
```

Есть у кого нибудь идеи, или опыт в сие деянии ?

[image: Вот как выглядит игра]

Comment: Вы уверены что все эти ресурсы зашиты в один экзешник?

Comment: Естественно нет